# Using a credential file with terraform in AWS

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I started to learn Terraform with AWS today. I created a file main.tf in vscode and placed the code below in it.
I want to create a s3 bucket

```
        provider "aws" {
          region = "us-east-2"
        }

        resource "aws_s3_bucket" "first_bucket" {
          bucket = "kunta-first-bucket"
        }
```

I created a credentials folder and place a file in it with my access key and secret key
in my windows 11 path below.

```
        C:\Users\Alex\.aws\credential\test.txt
```

Inside the credentials folder I created a file called test.txt with the content below

```
        [default]
        aws_access_key_id = <xxxxxxxxx>
        aws_secret_access_key = <xxxxxxxxx>
```

The above did not work and I got all kinds of error. I knew the problem was gaining access to
my credential file but when I applied my access key and secret key in my provider it all worked.
I know this is a bad practice.

```
        provider "aws" {
          access_key = "xxxxxx"
          secret_key = "xxxxxx"  
          region = "us-east-2"
        }
```

Is there a problem with the way I set my credentials file? Is there a better way to do it?
I also set as environment variables and still no luck.

Comment: "The above did not work and I got all kinds of error." Will you be sharing those errors with us?

Comment: Also, `C:\Users\Alex\.aws\credential\test.txt` isn't the right spot, I don't think. Mine go in `.aws/credentials`. If you have the AWS CLI installed, do `aws configure`.

Comment: I don't have the AWS CLI installed but I can install it. So is the credentials a folder or a file. Where will i be adding these keys? I think this is the part I am missing. What will aws configure do for me?

Comment: `credentials` is a file, not a folder. No extension, at least not on Mac/Linux; I can't speak 100% to Windows. You've just put it in the wrong location; your file *contents* looks fine.